# Using Cordova cross-platform mixed Google Maps APIs?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm currently working on compiling an HTML5 webapp using the Google Maps API to native Android and iOS apps using Cordova. I've got an initial build working now for iOS and Android.

The next step, for performance, will be to swap out the javascript Google Maps API for the native API in Android and iOS (using the [Google Maps Plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)). I'd like to maintain the ability to run in browser, however. Unfortunately the API for the javascript and the native plugins is slightly different.

I was hoping for some suggestions on the best/easiest way to do this. Some ideas I have:

1. Add (at least the pieces I need) of the Google javascript API to the Cordova plugin. Is this a tall order?
2. Write a javascript wrapper that detects the platform and call the appropriate API. How can I detect this at runtime?

I'm also not sure if I should target Browser as a platform or just use the source as my web version.

Any tips would be appreciated!